# MVC 5 C# Standard Project with Authentication - how to create new users from an admin view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, model-view-controller, owin

I have a straightforward MVC5 project with the built-in Membership providers... So I can register a straight forward user and login, etc.

What is the most basic way to set up a form that I can create users from and apply Roles to..? I just want to be able to create users similar to how the old school method ASPNET used to.

Just a controller action and a form to write new users to the [AspNetUsers] table and apply Roles would be great.

Had a good look around for answers, there didn't seem to be any that fitted exactly although I'm open to be proven wrong.. thanks

Comment: You'd have to write something yourself. There is no out of the box solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK thanks, I just re-purposed the Register view and controller action - was fairly straightforward...